# Types of calls in CallLog.Calls.TYPE

Tags: android, phone-call

Can someone tell me which are all the types of calls in android in CallLog.Calls.TYPE?

I found this return 1 for Incoming(1), Outgoing(2) and Missed(3), 4 (VoiceMail), 5 (Rejected) and 6 (Refused List).

But i´m calling CallLog.Calls.TYPE and returns me a 10 (?) but i don´t know which type is?

And may be there are more types of calls..

Comment: all the stuff in `Calls` that ends with `_TYPE`. 5, 6 and 10 are not documented

Comment: yeah!, i know CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE, CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE, CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE, CallLog.Calls.VOICEMAIL_TYPE, but there are more than this and doesn´t show, i want more :(

Comment: Unfortunately if they aren't documented there, they are not part of the public API and thus you cannot rely on them being used consistently.

Comment: pff, :( ok I'll have to settle down with this, thank you

Comment: Also seeing return code of 5 and wondering where the documentation lies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [`CallLog.Calls.TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#TYPE) documentation, there are 7- incoming, outgoing, missed, voicemail, rejected, blocked and answered externally.

Those types correspond to the following `CallLog.Calls` constants:

- [`INCOMING_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#INCOMING_TYPE)
- [`OUTGOING_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#OUTGOING_TYPE)
- [`MISSED_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#MISSED_TYPE)
- [`VOICEMAIL_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#VOICEMAIL_TYPE)
- [`REJECTED_TYPE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#REJECTED_TYPE)
- [`BLOCKED_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#BLOCKED_TYPE)
- [`ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#ANSWERED_EXTERNALLY_TYPE)

Comment: This is not consistent with all the devices, some flavours of Android return haphazard integers.

Comment: Getting '10' Redmi 4A, Running 6.0.1. Don't know what it means!

Comment: When I choose VOICEMAIL_TYPE to add a call-log, it shows an error of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri content://call_log/calls cannot be used for voicemail record. Please set 'allow_voicemails=true' in the uri.` . Any idea how to fix this?